# Is there any difference between function(e){} and function(event){} in js

Tags: javascript

Codes 1

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="example.css">
<div class="d1">1  
    <div class="d2">2
        <div class="d3">3 
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
<script>
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div')
for(var i=0; i<divs.length; i++) {
  divs[i].onclick = function(e) {
    e = e || event
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement
    this.style.backgroundColor='yellow'
    alert("target = "+target.className+", this="+this.className)
    this.style.backgroundColor = ''
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Codes 2

```
<html>
<body onkeypress = "show_key(event.which)">
<form method="post" name="my_form">
The key you pressed was:
<input type="text" name="key_display" size="2"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_key ( the_key )
{console.log(the_key);
       document.my_form.key_display.value = String.fromCharCode ( the_key );
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Question:

1.In codes 1, Even I change `function(e) {e = e || event`  to `function(a) { e = a || event`, it still work, But In codes 2, if I change `show_key(event.which)` to `show_key(e.which)`, it does not work, why?

2.I often see `function(e){}` or `function(event)` in js, are they the same? can I use this way: `function(a){}` or `function(b){}`?

Comment: I didn't read your code, but for the question: the parameter names are just different. That's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The identifier `event` is not special in JavaScript, you can freely replace it with `e`, `a` or `b` etc. in function arguments without changing its meaning.

However, renaming a variable (no matter if it's `event` or not) has some consequences outside the function: the new name might shadow a variable of the same name in outer scope (i.e. the code surrounding the function), and the inner functions have to be changed as well.

In `<body onkeypress="show_key(event.which)">` in *Codes 2*, the browser creates the local variable named `event` before running the *onkeypress* event handler. It's like creating `function(event) { show_key(event.which); }` and then calling that function whenever a key is pressed. The name of the function argument is always `event`, and you can't change it, so in that sense it's special.

Comment: but why for codes 2, i can not change `show_key(event.which)` to `show_key(e.which)`?

Comment: @user2507818 because you mix the name of a global object `event` (it's actually an _argument_ taken from the `window` object; you _can't_ change it) with the name of the formal _parameter_ `the_key` of the `show_key` function. if you simply pass `event` to the function in your body attribute, then you are free to change the name of the parameter either to `event`, or to `e`, and then simply access `event.which` or `e.which` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

This is a function declaration:

```
function xy(a) {
    return a + 1;
}
```

You could translate it to:;

```
function xy() {
    var a = arguments[0];
    return a + 1;
}
```

While `arguments` is the array of arguments that you provide when you call the function:

```
xy(1, 2);   // -->  arguments = [1, 2]
```

You can name `a` whatever you want, since it is simply a variable declaration. That is why the following code is equally valid:

```
function xy(b) {
    return b + 1;
}
```

When you call the function `xy` like this:

```
xy(a);
```

this means that you pass to `xy` the value of a variable `a`. That is why there has to be a variable `a` that was declared before the function call:

```
var a = 4;
xy(a);
```

If you change `a` in you function call to `b` it will fail, since `b` is not defined:

```
var a = 4;
xy(b);  //where is b???
```

And this exactly why you can change this

```
function(e) {e = e || event}
```

to this:

```
function(a) {e = a || event}
```

but if you try to change this (which is a function call):

```
show_key(event.which)
```

to this:

```
show_key(e)
```

it expects `e` to be a already declared variable which it isn't. `event` however, is a property of the `window` object (at least in internet explorer), which means it is accessable from everywhere.